# Include google analytic in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-analytics

I have chrome extension which contains a  manifest file and a js file. How can i include google analytics in my chrome extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This could be helpful](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics)

Read the documentation and include the desired file in manifest and js script.